# Optimization of very large collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

---

I have a very large collectionview (that will just keep getting bigger) and problem is, for everytime the collectionview gets bigger, data renders more slowly and with lag. Are there any good tricks to optimize this? For now all of the logic for defining what displays in each cell is fetched from one array called "totsalesOrders", containing a custom object named BUYProduct. These are fetched and added to the array each 50 items.

Here is the code for the cell for indexpath:

```
BUYProduct * product = [totsalesOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //View for trending feed
    CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell *cell =
    (CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

    BUYImageLink * imgLink = [[product imagesArray] firstObject];
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imgLink.sourceURL
                      placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                          NSNumber * width = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.width];
                          [imageSizesW setValue:width forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
                          NSNumber * height = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.height];
                          [imageSizesH setValue:height forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
                          [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    }];
    cell.productDict = product;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.2f;

    return cell;
```

Unfortunately, we have to use some sort of optimization for each cell and therefore calculating the cell size dynamically, this is done through:

```
        CGSize siz;
    if ([imageSizesW objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]] != nil) {
        NSNumber * imgWi = [imageSizesW objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
        NSNumber * imgHe = [imageSizesH objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
        //NSLog(@"Numbers:%@, %@", imgWi, imgHe);
        CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell * cell = (CHTCollectionViewWaterfallCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"product name:%@    and it's collection: %lu", cell.productDict.title,(unsigned long)cell.productDict.collections.count);
        float halfwi = collectionView.frame.size.width/2-15;
        float factor = halfwi/([imgWi floatValue]);
        float height = ([imgHe intValue]) * factor;
        //float ediHeight = (roundf(height/10.0))*10.0;
        //NSLog(@"FLOATS %f, %f %f",halfwi, ediHeight, factor);
        if (([imgHe floatValue]-[imgWi floatValue])<10&&([imgHe floatValue]-[imgWi floatValue])>-10) {
            siz = CGSizeMake(halfwi, height);
        }else{
            siz = CGSizeMake(halfwi, height*1.5);
        }
    }
    else {
        siz = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    }
    return siz;
```

When I analyze the number of memory which the app drains it is practically nothing, but still we have some lags when the number of cells in the collectionview increases.

thanks,
Martin

Comment: Why are you using NSNumber which you then. We'd to continually unbox? Have you used the time profiler instrument to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Not sure, was kind of a last minute solution! Thanks for pointing it out, will fix it right away

Comment: @Paulw11 never heard of that before, but analyzing CPU-usage shows that tasks are being divided through threads evenly and no adverse effect when the number of cells increase

Comment: Strangely enough, when running in instruments, app performs slightly better and with less lag than when just doing normal build

Comment: An instrumented build is more optimized and turns off the debug stuff

Comment: Does that mean that it will perform that way once released? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, an instrumented build should have the same performance as the release build.  You can also archive a build and use ad-hoc distribution.